# change a label from another view

Tags: iphone

I have a label on my main View. I have a button which brings me to another view. On it I have a button to change my label which is on the main view.

How can I do this? I included a projet, could someone help me please...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use a delegate protocol:

**in the second view h add :**

```
@protocol viewControllerDelegate;

@interface viewController : UIView  

id < viewControllerDelegate > delegate;  
@property (nonatomic, assign) id < QuickViewControllerDelegate > delegate;

@end

@protocol viewControllerDelegate

- (void)viewController:(ViewController *)controller stringForLabel:(NSString*)string; 

@end
```

**in the second view m file call:**

```
[delegate quickViewController:self
stringForLabel:@"your string"];
```

**in the main view h file add:  , like that:**

```
 @interface MainView:UIViewController<viewControllerDelegate>
```

**in the main view m file:**

first: when you init the second view don't forget to add:

```
secondview.delegate = self;
```

other wise it wont work.

second: add the delegate function:

```
 - (void)viewController:(ViewController*)controller stringForLabel:(NSString*)string{

    //set the label from the string passed

    lable.text = string;

    }
```

hope it will help
shani

Comment: could you integrate it in the projet please?

Answer (score 3):

O.K i usually don't do that but for now...

this are your files after i have change them -

**View1 .h** (try to name those files with a capital letter);

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol View1Delegate;


@interface View1 : UIViewController {

    id <View1Delegate> delegate;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btn_changelbl;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btn_back;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <View1Delegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_changelbl;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_back;

-(IBAction) backToMain:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) changeLabel:(id)sender;
@end


@protocol View1Delegate 
- (void)view1:(View1*)controller labelNeedsChage:(BOOL)needsChange stringForLabel:(NSString*)string;

@end
```

**View1.m**

```
#import "View1.h"
#import "testViewController.h"

@implementation View1
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize btn_changelbl;
@synthesize btn_back;

-(IBAction) backToMain:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [delegate view1:self labelNeedsChage:NO stringForLabel:nil];

}

-(IBAction) changeLabel:(id)sender{
    [delegate view1:self labelNeedsChage:YES stringForLabel:@"new text"];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [btn_changelbl release];
    [btn_back release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

**TestViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "View1.h"

@interface testViewController : UIViewController<View1Delegate> {

    IBOutlet UILabel *lb_test;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btn_changeView;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lb_test;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_changeView;

-(IBAction) changeView:(id)sender;
@end
```

**TestViewController.m**

```
#import "testViewController.h"
#import "view1.h"

@implementation testViewController

@synthesize lb_test;
@synthesize btn_changeView;

-(IBAction) changeView:(id)sender {
    View1 *myView = [[View1 alloc] init];
    myView.delegate=self;
    [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
}


- (void)view1:(View1*)controller labelNeedsChage:(BOOL)needsChange stringForLabel:(NSString*)string{
    if(needsChange){
        lb_test.text=string;
    }

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [lb_test release];
    [btn_changeView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Thats it.
by the way:
you had many small mistakes that i have fixed. look at the fixes to try to understand them.

Comment: thank you very shani :D I'll try it in some hours and I'll let you know.

Comment: thanks very much shani, I now have an example to work on my project :D I'm a newbie...thank you :D